# Value not updating in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a value from a model by passing to request body value. But sometimes it's updating and sometimes not updating.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? **PUT** is my method.

**Code**

**TS**

```
accept = (req, res) => {
    this._model.update({
        person1: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.person1),
        person2: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.person2)
    }, {
        $set: {
            status: "active"
        }
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
           res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Model**

```
{
   "_id":"5d2715cea9ae086ac295c6d8",
   "status":"pending",
   "person1":ObjectId("5cfe4dd898fd225ef1c99ded"),
   "person2":ObjectId("5d02197e2859122fa28c189b")
}
```

**Request**

```
{
    "person1": "5cfe4dd898fd225ef1c99ded",
    "person2": "5d02197e2859122fa28c189b"
}
```

**Response**

```
  {    "ok": 0,
       "n": 0,
      "nModified": 0
   }
```

Comment: Make sure that the person1 and person2 saved as Object Id

Comment: @Chris your Request object person1 and person2 have been inverted. You have person1 id in person2 and vice versa

Comment: yes they are object id `person1 : ObjectId("5d02197e2859122fa28c189b", person2 : ObjectId("5cfe4dd898fd225ef1c99ded")`

Comment: @gypsyCoder I have updated. Kindly take look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using async/await. you can do it also using callback

```
let ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId
accept = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await  this._model.update({
            person1: new ObjectId(req.body.person1),
            person2: new ObjectId(req.body.person2)
        }, {
            $set: {
                status: "active"
            }
        })
        if(data.nModified == 1 && data.ok == 1) {
            return res.send(data);
        }
        return res.send("not updated");
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the person1 and person2 saved as Object Id
try

```
accept = (req, res) => {
    this._model.update({
        person1: req.body.person1,
        person2: req.body.person2
    }, {
        $set: {
            status: "active"
        }
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
           res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `person1` and `person2` are objectId. Do you want me to send as raw `req.body` ?

Comment: First of all, I think you should try the query first 
like trying to make it find not update with the first object and make sure that the object in the data
then make update I think this will show you where the problem

Comment: update is deprecated it seems ? What are you using @mohammed

Comment: I will tell you something to do first of all make two variables for this model (query, data) then try to find with just the query, if the data returned right then try UpdateOne or UpdateMany

Comment: Am just telling him How the query should be with same code he is writing
the problem was in the query what ever the function he is calling